# Building the protobuf library as a static library

Tags: build, shared-libraries, static-libraries, bazel

Is there a elegant way to build the protobuf library as a static library with  bazel?

If not then not is there a way to build in bazel and get the absolute path of the so for linking?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a library as static using the `linkstatic` option. See: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.linkstatic

As for linking, you should let Bazel generate the linker flags for you by adding the Protobuf library to the `deps` list. See: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.deps